# Django form for 2 related model

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I want to make forms that submit individually these 2 models. Somehow i managed to get views for them. However, i got error saying:

> unbound method full_clean() must be called with MCQuestions instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

my details are:

models.py

```
class MCQuestions(models.Model):
    question = FroalaField(null=True, blank=True)
    qcategory = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name="MCCategory", blank=True)


class MCAnswers(models.Model):
    questionid = models.ForeignKey(MCQuestions, related_name="mc_answer")
    a = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    z_a = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    z_b = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    z_c = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    z_d = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
 def AddMCQuestions(request, course_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        aform = MCQuestionsForm(request.POST)
        bform = MCAnswersForm(request.POST, instance=MCQuestions)
        #cat = Categories.objects.filter(cid=course_id)
        aform_valid = aform.is_valid()
        **bform_valid = bform.is_valid()**
        if aform_valid and bform_valid:
            a = aform.save(commit=False)
            a.qcategory_id = course_id
            a.save()
            b = bform.save(commit=False)
            b.save()
            return HttpResponse('question added')
    else:
        aform = MCQuestionsForm()
        bform = MCAnswersForm()
        bform.qcategoryid = a
   return render(request, 'teacher/mcquestionadd.html', {'aform': aform, 'bform': bform})
```

and error is highlighting `bform_valid = bform.is_valid()`

Comment: `instance=MCQuestions` has to be an instance of `MCQuestions `  - not the class itself.

Comment: Actually @karthikr, it should be an instance of MCAnswers.

Comment: Hmm, instance of MCAnswers? instance you mean this:

`instance=MCQuestions.questionid` and i got this error

`'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute '_meta'`

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
bform = MCAnswersForm(request.POST, instance=MCQuestions)
```

should be:

```
bform = MCAnswersForm(request.POST, instance=answers)
```

where `answers` is an instance of `MCAnswers`. There is no answer yet in your view (you are about to create it) so just remove it from your code for now.

---

You will need to add prefixes to your forms so the validation will work properly and you better give meaningful names to these (not `aform`)

```
    question_form = MCQuestionsForm(request.POST, prefix="question")
    answer_form = MCAnswersForm(request.POST, prefix="answers")
```

---

Finally to save, do this - you are missing the link from the question to the answer:

```
  if question_form.is_valid() and answer_form.is_valid():
        question = question_form.save(commit=False)
        question.qcategory_id = course_id
        question.save()

        answer = bform.save(commit=False)
        answer.question = question
        answer.save()

        return HttpRedirect(reverse('...'))
```